# how to pivot with two columns in sql

Tags: sql, pivot

[image]

I meet a stuck when trying to working with Sql pivot
I am not a master sql and i trying to convert my table to pivot for the report
I am so appriciate for any helps

I can pivot one column plandate/actual date at one

Comment: Please don't link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text 1) Provide sample data 2) provide the result you want to achieve, based on the sample data 3) provide the SQL you've managed to write on your own

Comment: We don't post images of technical information like code, sample data, or results here. It's the fastest way I've seen other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL language has a very strict rule: you MUST know how many columns you want at query compile time, before looking at ANY table data. Therefore **this will not be possible in a single query** if you have an arbitrary number of processes/subprocesses .

Instead, you must do this over three steps:

1. Run a query to find out what columns you will need
2. Build a new SQL statement dynamically using the results from step 1
3. Run the query built in step 2.

As a practical matter, this kind of dynamic PIVOT is better handled in client code or by the reporting tool, rather than with SQL.